# How to extract data after button auto click on webpage during webpage extraction

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I want to extract data from webpage after auto button click.Currently i am able to click on that particular button but unable to extract data after button click event.I am using below mentioned code for extraction.I am using page refresh option but it still not displaying new value after click event.Webpage and code detail is given below.From webpage i want to extract phone number after clicking button.
Webpage:
https://www.leboncoin.fr/ventes_immobilieres/1926184517.htm?ac=558505705

Click event

```
Set btn = html.getElementsByClassName("_2qvLx _3osY2 _35pAC _1Vw3w _kC3e _32ILh _2L9kx _30q3D _1y_ge _3QJkO")
For Each Item In btn                                                                                         
a = Item.innerText                                                                                           
'MsgBox (a)                                                                                                  
Item.FireEvent ("onmousedown")                                                                               
Item.FireEvent ("onclick")                                                                                   
Item.Click                                                                                                   
'MsgBox (Item.innerText)                                                                                     
'btn.Click                                                                                                   
Exit For                                                                                                     
Next                                                                                                         
btn = ""                                                                                                     
Ie.Refresh                                                                                                   
Set html = Ie.Document                                                                                       
Set btn = html.getElementsByClassName("css-z4gyg3")                                                          
                                                                                                             
For Each Item In btn                                                                                         
MsgBox (Item.innerHTML)                                                                                      
a = Item.innerText                                                                                           
MsgBox (a)                                                                                                   
'Item.FireEvent ("onmousedown")                                                                              
'Item.FireEvent ("onclick")                                                                                  
'Item.Click                                                                                                  
'btn.Click                                                                                                   
Exit For                                                                                                     
Next
```

Comment: anyone have some idea regarding above issue?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your code doesn't work. First of all, `FireEvent()` no longer works (on most pages). Firstly, HTML events are no longer triggered this way and secondly, `btn.Click` is enough to execute a click. Furthermore, you always use `Exit For` for the first button. The button you want is the third in the node collection. It will never be reached. I haven't tried it, but a click on the button to display the phone number wants to establish a dial-up connection. This means that if you click on the button, you will leave IE. The focus is now on another application.

Comment: A few words about lbc: I really have a lot of experience with this platform. Over the years I have read out several million offers from there. But without telephone numbers. Since July 2019, the readout no longer works. Since then, lbc has been working with the company DataDome, which prevents web scraping. I scrape from Germany and after 10 accesses it stops. I have tried a few things, but DataDome knows its business. They are really good. https://datadome.co/fr/ If you plan to read out a lot of offers ... It might work with a proxy pool, but I haven't been able to do that till now.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed feedback.Click event is working and phone number is visible but i am unable to extract number after click event.

Comment: Please edit your question and post there your whole VBA code instead of the snippet.

Comment: Code already visible,no issue in click only issue in data extraction after click event i.e from following html code..<a class="_2qvLx _3osY2 _35pAC _1Vw3w _kC3e _32ILh _2L9kx _30q3D _1y_ge _3QJkO" href="tel:0647007670" title="Appeler" data-qa-id="adview_number_phone_contact">06 47 00 76 70<span class="styles_salesProspecting__3cGFU" data-tip="Opposé au démarchage commercial" data-place="left" currentitem="false">